# Share Y axis label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib plot, which is actually two subplots of different heights made to looks like a single disjointed plot.

[image]

I have done this using Gridspec:

```
outer = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[1,3])
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 1, subplot_spec = outer[0])
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0])
ax1.plot(no_rot,max_sd,'k*')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis Label')

gs2 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 1, subplot_spec = outer[1])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs2[0])
ax2.plot(no_rot,max_sd,'k*')
plt.xlabel('X Axis Label')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis Label')
```

I now want to just have one shared, centralised Y Axis label but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to store a reference to the label with:

```
yaxis_label = plt.ylabel('My Y-axis')
```

Then change its position in relative units, e.g.

```
yaxis_label.set_position((-0.05,0.5))
```

You might need to adjust the relative (x,y) here to position it properly since you have two subplots.

Alternatively, put your subplots explicitly in a figure and place a text label for the y-axis relative to the figure coordinates:

```
ax.text(0.05, 0.5, "My y-axis", transform=f.transFigure, rotation='vertical',
        verticalalignment='center')
```